# Apollo loading is always false on props change

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I am new to Apollo. Issue i am facing is that On initial (Mount/Render) network call is made and on prop change it isn't.

Following is simplified structure of my application.

```
<Component (has filters in state)>
  <QueryComponent filters = {...filters} (passed to query)>

    <Table onChange/>

  </QueryComponent>
<Component/>
```

```
QueryComponent Code

export const QueryComponent = ({ callback, filter }) => {

  // Data transformation from filter to vars(expected by Query)

  return (
    <Query
      handleLoading
      query={query}
      returnPartialData
      variables={vars}
      fetchPolicy="network-only"
      callback={callback}
      getData={function}
      entityType="xx"
    />
  );
};
```

```
Query returns ApolloQuery

<ApolloQuery
    returnPartialData={returnPartialData}
    partialRefetch={partialRefetch}
    {...rest}
  >
    {
      ({
        data,
        loading,
      }) => {
        if (loading) {
          return handleLoading
            ? (
              <Loading />
            )
            : callback({
              loading,
            });
        }

        const queryData = data && getData(data);
        const hasValidData = !!queryData && !!Object
          .values(queryData)
          .filter((val) => !!val)
          .length;

        if (!hasValidData) {
          return passThruMissingData
            ? callback({
              loading,
              ...queryData,
            })
            : (
              <EntityNotFound
                type={entityType}
              />
            );
        }

        let strippedData = { ...queryData };
        const isValueAnArray = Object.values(strippedData)[0] instanceof Array;

        if (isValueAnArray) {
          strippedData = transform(
            strippedData,
            (result, value, key) => {
              value.forEach(deepStripInvalid);

              // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
              result[key] = value;
            },
          );
        } else {
          deepStripInvalid(strippedData);
        }

        return callback({
          ...strippedData,
        });
      }
    }
  </ApolloQuery>
```

and `QueryComponent` has a Wrapper that has `Query as ApolloQuery` form `react-apollo` and it returns loader when **loading** is true.

In `<Table/>` component I have handler that updates the filters in Component which flows down into `<QueryComponent />`

On initial render Filters are passed down and i can see that network call has been made and loading state was true for a second and then change to false. When I interact with table onChange is called which updates the filters and they are passed to Query, but loading state return false and there is no network call.

I have tried to set `fetchPolicy="network-only"` and to `fetchPolicy="no-cache"` as well and there is still no network call.

Note: Currently there is no data on backend so initial query returns an empty array.

Behaviour I am expecting: When filters are changed query is called again and there should be a network call.

Note2: If I forcefully unmount and remount the `<QueryComponent>` then network request is made, but i would prefer to use Apollo's loading state to handle that.

**react-apollo**: "version": "2.5.8"

**apollo**: "version": "2.21.0"

Edited to include more details.

Comment: Mind sharing the `QueryComponent` code? It seems it is likely only making fetches in `componentDidMount` versus also doing so in `componentDidUpdate`, so OFC remounting it fetches data.

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese for the response. I don't think that should be a problem as I am using this same ```Query``` and ```ApolloQuery``` in another page where data is actually returned from the query and it behaves properly i.e loading is ```true``` and then ```false```. Also i was logging the **loading** above if(loading) in ```ApolloQuery```. It means that on each change i am reaching there but somehow ApolloQuery is not making a network call.

I have edited and updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone ends up coming to this question. Digging further into the problem I found that `Query` from `react-apollo` was ignoring `fetchPolicy: network-only or no-cache` discussed here in length https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/556 . This was closed due to inconsistency of people having this issue and some who didn't.

The way we solved it is by returning `refetch` with the data and on the trigger it wasn't sending a network call again we called `refetch` and it forcefully send the call again.